# Adobe Flash 11.5 r502 "Stops Working" in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, crash, flash-player

I would consider myself to be quite technical and I haven't had an issue with Windows in a long time, but recently, Firefox started to show that "Stopped Working" dialog each time I closed it, so I decided to completely cleanly uninstall Firefox (including scanning for registry entries, removing the Program Files folder, and removing the Roaming data folder).

After reinstalling, I now receive the "Stopped Working" dialog on Flash every time I view a flash-based page in Firefox. I've tried to uninstall Flash and reinstall it, but to no avail. Here is the crash report from the dialog:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: BEX
Application Name:   FlashPlayerPlugin_11_5_502_135.exe
Application Version:    11.5.502.135
Application Timestamp:  50b849af
Fault Module Name:  StackHash_cad8
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
Exception Offset:   6b8392cd
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Data: 00000008
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   cad8
Additional Information 2:   cad8af42b5aa650bf35704654eb8c9ee
Additional Information 3:   30e6
Additional Information 4:   30e63471c9c5c77a9680ae22de7d4c95
```

I am running Windows 7 64bit SP1, fully updated as of yesterday. I am using the latest version of Firefox (17.0.1) and I am using the setup file directly from Adobe for Flash. I've tested the same flash-based website in the latest version of Opera and the latest version of Chrome. While I have no issue using Chrome, my preferred development environment is Firefox.

I would have normally chosen to Google this, but do to the generic nature of Flash "not working", I was unable to dig through the myriad of posts of people having issues with Flash.

Any and all help is thoroughly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest you [uninstall Flash](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html), delete *all* directories (hidden or otherwise) related to Flash, Adobe and Macromedia from your system partition (be careful if you have other Adobe products installed!), optionally clean residual traces from the registry if you're comfortable with it, then reboot, reinstall and check once more.

Comment: That's interesting. I did not realize that Flash had it's own uninstaller. Unfortunately, I ran it, cleared up all traces of Flash (including go so far as to use CCleaner), rebooted, and reinstalled Flash and it still crashes. 

I also realize now I was a bit dim to test with Chrome; Chrome has it's own integrated version of Flash that is unrelated to the system version.

Comment: Does it crash only with Flash-based streaming video, or even simple Flash animations? Also, would a Firefox reinstall be possible? (Or can you at least try with a new profile?)

Comment: It appears to be triggered by any Flash content, whether it is video or a Flash-based advertisement. I have essentially nuked Firefox off my computer and tried to install it over again, and I still face the same results. I am assuming that the above crash report is not as helpful in determining what is wrong.

I wish Windows was like Android. I would logcat this in a heartbeat.

Comment: Have you tried the Adobe forum? Someone there might be able to make sense of the crash report. Also, does the IE plugin crash as well (even though it's not NPAPI based)?

Comment: It appears that will be my next step (although not one I am looking forward to). Thank you for your time and effort in attempting to help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same experience with Flash Player 11 r502 and resolved issue by downgrade of Flash Player.
This is the latest version which I don't have any problem with Firefox on Windows 7 64bit.

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/fp_11.4.402.278_archive.zip